# Ubuntu network manager: What is a system connection?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

When creating/editing a connection in the network manager, there is a checkbox that says "System connection". How is a system connection different from a non system connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **system connection** allows **all users** on the machine to connect to that network.

Newer versions of `NetworkManager` now label this setting `[x] all users may connect to this network` for clarity.

By enabling this and `[x] automatically connect to this network when available` *NetworkManager* will attempt to connect to the network even before your *display manager* (where users log in) loads.